# How to parse audit log entries from Stackdriver on GCP

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-python, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I'm trying to retrieve BigQuery audit logs using [Stackdriver Logging Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries?hl=ja#client-libraries-usage-python) in Python.

According to [the tutorial](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/logging/usage.html), the following code should be able to fetch log entries:

```
for entry in client.list_entries():
    do_something_with(entry)
```

However, this iterator just returns `ProtobufEntry` and I couldn't find how to get the actual log message from this object.

```
for entry in client.list_entries():
    print type(entry)
```

The above code produces the following output:

```
$ python log_test.py
<class 'google.cloud.logging.entries.ProtobufEntry'>
<class 'google.cloud.logging.entries.ProtobufEntry'>
<class 'google.cloud.logging.entries.ProtobufEntry'>
....
```

However, I couldn't find any way to parse those objects.

How can I parse actual log messages?

Answer (score 2):

The fields of a `ProtobufEntry` are listed [here](http://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logging/entries.html). If the payload is `None` use `payload_pb` instead as I found in the [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/logging/google/cloud/logging/entries.py#L198).

The following snippet worked for me:

```
from google.cloud import logging

client = logging.Client()
for entry in client.list_entries():
        timestamp = entry.timestamp.isoformat()
        print('* {}: {}'.format
              (timestamp, entry.payload_pb))
```

Comment: `payload_pb` is a binary blob in Protobuf format. Any idea how to parse it?